# What does "put your word beyond reproach" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Yes. You were made to be the witness, for your political naivete **put your word beyond reproach**;no one would believe you'd devise suck a story

What's the bold part mean?

I know that beyond reproach means:

beyond reproach
Perfect; unable to be criticized.
I have to scold some of my employees regularly, but Tom's behavior is beyond reproach.(source TFD)

and I know that the verb put is probably used in the past tense here or else it would contain the morpheme "s" at the end.

put
2. To cause to be in a specified condition: His gracious manners put me at ease.(source TFD)

Does it mean that he was made to be the witness because his political
naivete causes his words to be unable to be criticized(so everyone will believe him) Does this phrase sound natural? Is this phrase common?

Comment: The specific construction *[something] **put** [someone's] **word beyond reproach*** isn't exactly "unnatural", but it isn't at all common. I found no matches in Google Books for any of ***put** [my/your/his] [word/words] **beyond reproach***. But if I *had* to use something like this, I'd prefer plural ***words***. The singular (e.g. - "His word is his bond") normally refers to ***a promise or commitment*** - the plural works much better for ***judgements or assertions***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. To put (or place) something beyond reproach is to make that thing impossible to doubt or blame.

The fact (presumably well-known) of the person's political naivete made him very likely to be believed.

> be above/beyond reproach
>
> to not deserve any blame

[Be above/beyond reproach (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-above-beyond-reproach)

Comment: Thank you Michael :)